# New Safari crashes with Flash plugin, for me only?

Tags: macos, flash, safari

I have Safari 4.0.2. Ever since I did the upgrade to OSX 10.5.8, it's been crashing several times an hour. After viewing all of my installed plug ins, deleting them, and reinstalling, I have found the Flash plugins to be the culprit.

The thing is though, Safari has been out for a few days now, and I haven't seen this problem publicized at all. So I'm thinking - "it must be something I'm doing wrong, am I the only one having this problem?"

One page that crashes for me every time now is espn.com  I load the page, it renders, and then after a moment Safari hangs and I get the dreaded beach ball.

Any other ideas as to how I can clean this up?

Update - I have now started using [clicktoflash](http://rentzsch.github.com/clicktoflash/) as a workaround. But this is only working as a way for me to watch YouTube videos via h.26.4 If I have clicktoflash installed AND the Flash plugin installed at the same time, Safari is crashing everywhere - front page of YouTube, ESPN's homepage, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed in Safari 4.0.3. According to the release notes that they show in Software Update, there was a problem with one of the HTML 5 video tags, so that may have been the problem.

Comment: I don't know about you, but for me this behavior of crashing/hanging on youtube videos started with Safari 4.0.4 and Flash 10.0.r32. I think it's something that requires some component to be reinstalled. Also affected is iTunes, which won't show a UI after I force-quit safari from a hang.

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded to 10.5.8 which includes Safari 4.0.2 and have had no problems with Safari crashing. I suspect you have an addon loaded that may not be happy with Safari 4.

Comment: I'd agree with this - I found the beta a little flakey at times but the 4.0.2 (5530.19) build is fine (on 3 different, fully-up-to-date Leopards with no 3rd-party Safari plugins).

Comment: edited question to reflect an update

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing the latest version of Flash (10.0.32.18) from [Adobe](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) to see if that clears it up. You can check what version you have on [Adobe's Flash Version Check](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html).

If that fails you may want to check what Input Managers are installed. Several Safari "plug-ins" are actually implemented using Input Managers (eg. Safari Stand, Glims, Pith Helmet, 1Password, etc.) and tend to be much more fragile during upgrades. (One reason 1Password will always say it won't work whenever a new release of Safari comes out requiring a day delay while they test and release a version that will run on the new version).

Input Managers can be found at `~/Library/Input Managers/` and `/Library/Input Managers/`

It can be noted more as an aside that Flash Player will have it's own sandbox coming in Snow Leopard because of the amount of crashes caused by Flash Player. Personally I use ClickToFlash as a blocker and my anecdotal evidence over the last several months is that Safari is substantially more stable when only running Flash when necessary.

Comment: Great tip using ClickToFlash, I actually am gonna do this now. In the spirit of answering the question though - what do I do with the input managers? Delete them?

Comment: You can delete them or see if there are updates if you're interested in them. If you're not sure yet just move them out of the folder somewhere else (eg. your Desktop) and see if that helps.